# Azure pipeline detect build has ran more than once

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there an inbuilt variable in Azure pipeline that checks if a build has run more than once?
I want to add a condition where i skip the step if build has run more than once.

[image]

As you can see ive commited once which triggered the build then i ran a manual build on the same commit hash so i want to know if there is a way to find out how many times it ran so i can add condition to one of my steps in the pipeline to skip if its > 1

I can see we have predefined variables for failed builds but how about normal build attempts

```
System.JobAttempt
```

and

```
System.StageAttempt
```

Comment: So, it's not if the pipeline ran once, but if he ran once on a commit? I don't think it's available, you need to write a script to check..

Comment: maybe you'd like to have a look at [Batching CI runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs)